# ImportError: No module named dns.message

Tags: python, linux, dns

When I try to run `sudo python dns2proxy.py` in Ubuntu, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns2proxy.py", line 21, in <module>
    import dns.message
ImportError: No module named dns.message
```

I have the correct repository cloned ([see here for GitHub link](https://github.com/LeonardoNve/dns2proxy.git)) and I'm in the correct directory. I've tried running it in Kali linux and it works flawlessly. My intention is to do a `gnome-terminal -e "sudo python dns2proxy.py"` and make the command run in another terminal.

Comment: Download version 1.9.2 of dnspython from this [link] (https://www.dnspython.org/kits/1.9.2/)   and install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the command

```
pip install dnspython
```

or, if you are using your system Python (not recommended)

```
sudo pip install dnspython
```

This will install the `dns` package that is currently missing. If, as you say, you have cloned the repository and want to use that version (and possible edit it) you may instead use

```
[sudo] pip install -e .
```

from the cloned directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It gave me another error but I finaly figured it out with some help from this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698894/scapy-error-no-module-names-pcapy]